# TYPO3 V11 installation or configuration

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have have recovered a project in TYPO3 v11.3.0

My database is imported without error.

I access the installation tool :)

I have access to the typo3 login / password, but if I validate the form, I get the message "Not Found, The requested URL was not found on this server."

On the internet, I found the issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/94054

I tried the following fix: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-93048-BackendURLRewrites.html
but suddenly I no longer have access to either the instal tool or the login form, I simply have a TYPO3 error:

> Page not found The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: The
> requested page does not exist

Any ideas?

Comment: So what exactly did you change in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Had a same problem and it was because I had rewrite rules in apache site configuration so new rule in .htaccess where not executed.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example `.htaccess` file in the core that you can copy:

```bash
# cd into your web root
cd yourWebRoot/

# make a backup of your current .htaccess
mv .htaccess _.htaccess_old

# get a example .htaccess
cp typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess .htaccess
```

TYPO3 11 should work with that, now you can copy changes that you made in your old `.htaccess` into the new one.

Answer (score 1):

In case your using `typo3/cms-composer-installers` your files might be in `vendor/`, so your path to copy from might be here:

```bash
cp ../vendor/typo3/cms-install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess .htaccess
```